# On a page navigate an error is logged: bindShowMoreHotNetworkQuestions is not a function

Tags: bug, new-nav, hot-questions, pagination

When I'm on [`Questions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) and I click one of the page navigation buttons at the bottom to go the another page, the Developer console in Chrome shows

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: StackExchange.helpers.bindShowMoreHotNetworkQuestions is not a function  
>   at a (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=7527d2465dfb:4:15150)  
>   at Object.onLoadSucceeded (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=7527d2465dfb:4:22132)  
>   at Object.onLoadSucceeded (https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=7527d2465dfb:4:576)  
>   at https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=7527d2465dfb:3:29398
>   at i (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:27449)  
>   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:28213)  
>   at e.(anonymous function) (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:29192)  
>   at i (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:27449)  
>   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:2:28213)  
>   at y (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:4:22721)
> ```

I also reproduced this on Edge (but its developer console blows up inside of their own scripts due to this bug). My account has new nav enabled, in case that matters.
I couldn't repro on Firefox but I tested there with an account that is **NOT** on the new nav.  However @Braiam confirmed this to also happen in Firefox.

Due to this bug, clicking on the link *more hot questions* under the Hot Questions list causes a navigate to `/#` but doesn't expand the list.

Can this be looked at and if possible fixed?

Comment: Repro'd in Firefox, through different character count. https://gist.github.com/braiam/3a8181da73a221496bae2f66f02e9efa, new nav.